# missing data in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, missing-data

please help me to write this query.I have tried with leftjoin but its not working.

I have two table **tdate** and **tollname**. In **tdate** table I have dates only, like say of one month and second table tollname I have names of toll with dates.

I want to find toll wise dates missing from table tollname.

Table name: tdate

```
Dates
1
2
3
4
...

30
```

Tollname

```
Dates   TollName
1       A
1       B
1       C
5       A
5       B
6       C
9       B
12      A
12      B
12      C
28      A
28      B
30      C
```

Comment: WHERE tollname.tdate IS NULL

Comment: Can you show us the query you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c10af/3)

```
SELECT D.*
FROM tdate D
LEFT JOIN Tollname T
  ON  D.Dates = T.Dates
WHERE T.Dates IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.* from tdate d left join Tollname t on d.Dates = t.Dates
WHERE t.TollName is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `cross join` and `left join` (or equivalently `not exists`/`not in`).  This generates all the combinations of the `tollname` and `date`, and then returns the ones that are not present in your table:

```
select d.date, t.tollname
from tdate d cross join
     (select distinct tollname from tollname) t
where not exists (select 1
                  from tollname t2
                  where d.date = t2.date and t.tollname = t2.tollname
                 );
```

If you have a separate table with the `tollname`s, then you can use that instead of the subquery: